# Reading and Writing from a file in C++

Tags: c++, function, file, oop

WRITE
Suppose I have a program that asks the user a bunch of questions, and then i want that information to be written to a .txt file.
the user is asked about a certain car type and the number of the cars which is originally a struct, and then certain specifics of the car; for example, plate number, color.
In the file the header should contain the car type, and model.
How can I use a loop to write the specifics into the .txt file ?

I know that there should be a car_ptr[] thats also in the parameters of the write function, as well as the fileName and so on.

READ
The other case is having a .txt file and the car type, and model in the .txt file seperated by a .
how can i implement a Read function which reads this line, skips the period and reads the model
and the same goes to the car specifics (also seperated by . and should be read into program)
into the program ?

any help would be greatly appreciated !

---

I dont actually have a test program as I genuinely had no idea where to start.
but heres an example of the declaration.

```
WriteToFile(car* current_car[], string type, int numberOfCars , string FileName ){

ofstream file;

file.open(FileName);


if(file.is_open()){

file << "car type is " <<  type << " number of cars : " << numberOfCars <<  endl;

//here theres a loop that loops through every different model and color of the cars
//in the main the function will be called to store all those attributes onto the file inputted

}



}
```

Comment: Please use "Code Sample {}" format when posting code snippets.

Comment: Take a step back and break your problem down. You're describing a whole bunch of things and it's stopping you from progressing. Do one thing at a time. Start by writing code that prompts for just one input and then reads that one input. If you are struggling with that, then you're not ready for the next bit.

Comment: "as I genuinely had no idea where to start" SO isnt meant to replace documentation and basic tutorials. But at your current stage thats what you need. There are plenty of examples for reading/writing to/from a file. Pick one and try something. Once you do have some code and a concrete focused  question about an issue with your attempt we will be glad to help. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: You sound as if in need for a good tutorial. Maybe start here: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/basic-file-io/

Answer (score 1):

"I know there must be some car_ptr[]" No current C++ should not use "C" style arrays. If your teacher is still teaching those he needs to get up-to-date.
C++ has std::array (fixed size) and std::vector (dynamic size) both of which will know their size (which is much more safe)

In current C++ I would expect something more like this :

I did not match your assignment, that is still for you to figure out.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// Always model your data
struct car_t
{
    std::string brand;
    std::string license_plate_number;
    // etc
};


// By overloading stream operators you can
// write to file, console and anything else that is a stream
// and the same is true for reading.

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const car_t& car)
{
    os << car.brand << " " << car.license_plate_number;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, car_t& car)
{
    is >> car.brand >> car.license_plate_number;
    return is;
}

// Saving cars accepts a vector (you really should not be using "C" style array
// and/or raw pointers of any kind)
void save_cars(const std::vector<car_t>& cars)
{
    std::ofstream output_file("cars.txt");
    for(const auto& car : cars)
    {
        // the overloaded << operator from earlier reads writes one car to the file
        output_file << car << "\n";
    }
}

// the auto will be resolved by the compiler to be a std::vector<car_t>
auto load_cars()
{
    std::ifstream input_file("cars.txt");
    std::vector<car_t> cars;
    car_t car;

    // the overloaded >> operator from earlier reads one car from the file
    while(input_file >> car)
    {
        cars.push_back(car);
    }
    return cars;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<car_t> cars{ {"volvo","123-abc"}, {"buick", "555-ccc"}, {"nissan", "876-bbg"}};
    save_cars(cars);
    auto loaded_cars = load_cars();

    for(const auto& car : loaded_cars)
    {
        std::cout << car << "\n";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your efforts and answering my question. 
However, my professor is asking for a write and a read function, unfortunately I cant  use overloaded operators.
nonetheless thank you so much

Comment: No problem :) My answer is not only written for you, but also for other people wanting to do file IO right. Also a LOT of professors still don't teach C++ but some strange kind of hybrid of "C" and "C++" that in practice will only lead to low quality unsafe and buggy code. At least this way you know somewhere in your future you should be prepared to change from whatever your professor teaches you to something else.

Comment: You could do me a favor and show this example to your professor, as well as this video [Stop teaching "C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) and these [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). If he can change his training material to be more in line with these principles his students will learn things much closer to what is needed in practice. :)

Comment: Yeah well im in a german university and the professor is very unapproachable and his assignments are very detailed and i couldnt give you the same exact assignment for obvious reasons. I agree that his material is very outdated and not really used in practice and unfortunately im not in charge.... i just want to pass :(
thanks again

Comment: I am Dutch, but I am aware of the (more) hierarchical structure at german universities. So I can understand your position (schade). Sorry I can't do more. I graduated ages ago, but at least at my university there was always the possibiliy to inform some council that teaching was not of good enough quality and professors in general were quite approachable to start with.